# How to perform "date-math" in typst?

Tags: typst

I want to always get either today's date (assuming today is a friday) or the next week's friday.
How would I go about implementing the same mechanic in Typst?
Within the documentation I have not yet found a way to perform "date-math" like shown above.

In Python I could do something like this:

```py
report_date = date.today() + timedelta((5 - date.today().isoweekday()) % 7)
```

In Typst I can (seemingly) only elegantly cover the "today is friday" branch:

```rust
#let report_date = if datetime.today().weekday() == 5 {
  datetime.today().display("[month repr:long] [day] [year]")
} else {
  ... # TODO
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the `Duration` type for performing date arithmetic: [Duration Type](https://typst.app/docs/reference/foundations/duration/).
You can more or less 1:1 translate your Python snippet like this:

```rust
#let report-date = datetime.today() + duration(days: calc.rem(5 - datetime.today().weekday(), 7))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would have never looked for a duration type.